# How can I paint inside corners of textured walls at the ceiling or baseboard?

Tags: walls, painting, ceiling, repainting, texture

In [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26528/how-can-i-get-a-straight-line-at-the-ceiling-when-painting-a-textured-wall), techniques are described to paint the edge of a textured wall along a textured ceiling. How can I paint inside corners though? Mashing the brush into the corner seems to do OK, but it doesn't give a great result. I also wonder what that does to the brush, pushing the bristles out like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a paint shield as pictured below and an Angled brush as mentioned in your link you should get your desired effect - straight clean lines.

[image: Paint Shield]